# log4 file not loaded in wildfly camel subsystem

Tags: java, apache-camel, wildfly, apache-camel-cdi, wildfly-12

This is my environment

- Wildfly 12.0.0.Final
- WildFly-Camel 6.1.0 (WildFly-Camel 6.1.0 provides Camel-2.21.1 integration with WildFly-12.0.0)
- Oracle jdk 1.8.0_112 64 bits

I have created a maven project

- Group Id : org.wildfly.camel.archetypes
- Artifact Id : wildfly-camel-archetype-cdi
- Version : 6.1.0

I have coded the following route

```
@ApplicationScoped
@ContextName("camel-cdi-context")
public class RouteTestLog extends RouteBuilder{

    private static final Logger miLog = LoggerFactory.getLogger("testLogger");

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        Supplier<LocalDateTime> now = LocalDateTime::now;

        from("timer:simple?period=1000") // every second            
            .setBody( now ) // I set the body as the current LocalDateTime
            .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, miLog, "This is a message ${body}") //     I log it using the log component
            .process(new Processor() {              
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    miLog.error("This is a message inside a processor " +     exchange.getIn().getBody(LocalDateTime.class));
                }
            })
            .process().body( System.out::println ); // I log it in the     standard output for debug my test :S
    }//configure
}//RouteTestLog
```

And I have also written the following log4j2 xml configuration file. It is placed under src/main/resources directory. In the target WAR the file is located in **WEB-INF\classes\log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <configuration status="debug">
    <appenders>     
        <file name="testAppender" fileName="logs/test.log" append="false"/>
        <file name="rootApender"  fileName="logs/root.log" append="false"/>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>       
        <Logger name="testLogger" level="all" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="testAppender"/>
        </Logger>       
        <Root level="all">
            <AppenderRef ref="rootApender" />
        </Root>
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

When I deploy the generated war into the Wildfly 12 server patched with the Wildfy-camel subsystem. I use the **standalone-camel-full.xml** configuration file with no changes. I can see in the server.log the following lines.

```
2018-06-11 14:47:38,492 ERROR [testLogger] (Camel (camel-cdi-context) thread #1 - timer://simple) This is a message 2018-06-11T14:47:38.489
2018-06-11 14:47:38,497 ERROR [testLogger] (Camel (camel-cdi-context) thread #1 - timer://simple) This is a message inside a processor 2018-06-11T14:47:38.489
2018-06-11 14:47:38,499 INFO  [stdout] (Camel (camel-cdi-context) thread #1 - timer://simple) 2018-06-11T14:47:38.489
```

Which exactly what I want to log. But none of my appenders configurated in my log4j file is created. Everything is logged under the server.log of the Wildfly 12 server.

In the Wildfly Camel [documentation](http://wildfly-extras.github.io/wildfly-camel/) I cannot find any references to logging. The Wildfly 12 [administration guide, Logging Configuration](http://docs.wildfly.org/12/Admin_Guide.html#Logging) talks about a parameter called **use-deployment-logging-config** to be included in the logging subsystem section of the configuration xml (standalone-camel-full.xml)

From the docs

> use-deployment-logging-config
>
> The use-deployment-logging-config
>   controls whether or not your deployment is scanned for per-deployment
>   logging. If set to true, the default, per-deployment logging is
>   enabled. Set to false to disable this feature.
>
> 9.4.2. Per-deployment Logging
>
> Per-deployment logging allows you to add a logging configuration file to your deployment and have the logging
>   for that deployment configured according to the configuration file. In
>   an EAR the configuration should be in the META-INF directory. In a WAR
>   or JAR deployment the configuration file can be in either the META-INF
>   or WEB-INF/classes directories.
>
> The following configuration files are allowed:
>
> logging.properties
>
> jboss-logging.properties
>
> log4j.properties
>
> log4j.xml
>
> jboss-log4j.xml
>
> You can also disable this functionality by changing the
>   use-deployment-logging-config attribute to false.

I have test the name of my log4 file from log4j2.xml to log4j.xml but it is still not loaded.

I have also set the use-deployment-logging-config property in the standalone-camel-full.xml file. Even that it is said in the documentation it defaults to true. Again the same result. My log files are not created.

I think the file is not even loaded as if I make a syntax error inside it, that error is never shown during the deployment or server startup.

This is also my efective pom.xml from the Eclipse IDE, in case there is a missing dependency

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-jul</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

Any ideas why my file is not loaded?

Comment: A basic Camel CDI app with worked for me with [Per-deployment Logging](http://docs.wildfly.org/12/Admin_Guide.html#per-deployment-logging) after I converted your logging config back to the log4j 1.x format. I also didn't bother adding any logging dependencies into my pom.xml, because the WildFly logging subsystem automatically adds them to your deployment. I used a 'provided' scope dependency for camel-cdi which transitively pulls in slf4j.

Comment: @JamesNetherton you are right. I have written a log4j.xml file using the log4j 1.x format and it works great. There are still some loose ends like [link](https://github.com/wildfly-extras/wildfly-camel/issues/2256). Why do we have to write it in 1.x format if 2.x is supported as far as I understand it. And something really interesting to note. If you print something with System.out, it will go over the root appender not the standar output of the wildfy server. So it may apper the route is never executed or configured. This has driven me crazy for over an hour.

Comment: Try setting the `add-logging-api-dependencies` and `use-deployment-logging-config` to false. Or use a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` and exclude the logging subsystem.